# jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js newsticker modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, document

I am developing a website which have a scrolling newsticker in a strip using jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js.

page address is: http://www.designforce.us/demo/ticker/index.html

When we hover the mouse on the newsticker, strip is stop. At this stage i want to show a popup box right under the current li with its text. something i've done and when we hover the mouse pointer over the strip, newsticker stops and box is showing with its text.

PROBLEM:
jquery.li-scroller newsticker have a wrapper with {overflow:hidden} so if i add the popup box withing li then its not showing. Thats why i've coded the popup (.tickPop) withing a seperate space and white some script of jquery document ready. my script is:

```
$('ul#ticker01 li').each(function(e){
    var iClass;
    $(this).hover(function(){
        iClass = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).css('height',$('tickPop').height()+30)
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var left = offset.left;
        var top = offset.top+20;
        var iWidth = $(this).width();
        var sText = $(this).children().html();
        $(this).css('background','#f6f4f4');
        $('.tickPop').css('left',left);
        $('.tickPop').css('top',top);
        $('.tickPop').css('width',iWidth);
        $('.tickPop').css('display','block');
        $('.tickPop').text(sText);
     }, function(){

        $('.tickPop').mouseleave(function(){
            bHovering = false;
            $(this).css('display','none');
        });

         $(this).css('background','transparent');
         //$('.tickPop').css('display','none');
         if(iClass == 'Yellow')
            $(this).css('background','url(images/icon-yellow.jpg) left center no-repeat');
        else
            $(this).css('background','url(images/icon-white.jpg) left center no-repeat');

    });

});
```

popup box called $('.tickPop') is hidden by default and when user hover on newsticker then jquery function set the attribute $('.tickPop').css('display','block') and it is visible.

Now problem is that as we move the mouse pointer over the popup box then newsticker is again start scrolling while i want when we mouseleave from the popup box then newsticker should start.

Dear Experts, Please advise..............?
Looking forward for a kind response.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify jquery li-scroller sources.

watch this code (from li-scroller sources):

```
function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
                $strip.animate({left: '-='+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){$strip.css("left", containerWidth); scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);});
                }
                scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);             

                                // $strip = $(this) so it triggers when you're hover a news
                $strip.hover(function(){
                jQuery(this).stop();
                },
                function(){
                var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
                var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
                var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
                scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
                });
```

You should add something like:

```
     var popup = jQuery('.tickPop');
     popup.hover(function(){
                    $strip.stop();
                           },
                           function(){
                            var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
                            var residualSpace = offset.left + stripWidth;
                            var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
                            scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
                    });
```

I didn't test that code but should work....

P.S. Sorry for the indentation